# Remove text from every entry in a dataframe column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a column with datetime information I need to isolate from the text afterward. The Column is the DateTime column in the following dput snippet:

```
structure(list(DateTime = c("13:30:00.827: <- $HCHDG", "13:30:01.834: <- $HCHDG",
```

"13:30:02.825: <- $HCHDG", "13:30:03.833: <- $HCHDG", "13:30:04.824: <- $HCHDG",
"13:30:05.831: <- $HCHDG", "13:30:06.838: <- $HCHDG", "13:30:07.829: <- $HCHDG",
"13:30:08.837: <- $HCHDG", "13:30:09.827: <- $HCHDG", "13:30:10.835: <- $HCHDG",
"13:30:11.826: <- $HCHDG", "13:30:12.833: <- $HCHDG", "13:30:13.824: <- $HCHDG",
"13:30:14.831: <- $HCHDG", "13:30:15.839: <- $HCHDG", "13:30:16.830: <- $HCHDG"

As you can see, each time stamp is followed by `: <- $HCHDG` which is what I need to remove, from every single entry. How do I do this? I'm a beginner and this is beyond the scope of what I know thus far.

Comment: Please post the full ``dput()`` rather than a snippet.

Answer (score 1):

In `base R`you can use `sub` and backreference `\\1`:

```
sub("(\\d+:\\d+:\\d+\\.\\d+).*", "\\1", x)
[1] "13:30:00.827" "13:30:01.834"
```

or:

```
sub("(.*?)(: <-.*)", "\\1", x)
```

In both cases you divide the string into two capturing groups, the first of which you remember in `sub`s replacement argument.

In `stringr` you can use `str_extract` and positive lookahead `(?=...)`:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(x, ".*(?=: <-)")
```

Here you extract that substring that occurs right before the substring `: <-`

Data:

```
x <- c("13:30:00.827: <- $HCHDG", "13:30:01.834: <- $HCHDG")
```

Comment: Dear Mr. Ruehlemann, may I ask in the positive lookahead structure, whatever character we put in `...` is considered or only the first one? for example in your solution whether it checks `.*` followed by only `:` or the whole `: <-` ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The three dots are just a placeholder for whatever substring/pattern you define in the lookaround.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm beginning to take regex in earnest so I pay a close attention to everyone's code :)

Comment: Sure, no prob. Regex is powerful and fascinating, absolutely worth learning

Comment: Thanks indeed, I'm sure there is much to learn from you for me in this field. Yes it's very powerful and I noticed it could help us save some lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

Using `str_remove`

```
library(stringr)
str_remove(x, ":\\s+.*")
[1] "13:30:00.827" "13:30:01.834"
```

#### data

```
x <- c("13:30:00.827: <- $HCHDG", "13:30:01.834: <- $HCHDG")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you should use:

```
sub(': <- \\$HCHDG', '', dataframe$ColName)
```

Answer (score 0):

use \\ for special characters

```
gsub("\\$HCHDG|\\:|<|\\-|\\s+", "", dataframe$ColName)
```